# Container Iterator Template for one value type

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, containers

you helped me before so here I am again with another question in hope for an answer.

I have a function that processes a range of `std::complex<float>` values. My initial attempt of a function definition was

```
// Example 1
using namespace std; // not in original code
Errc const& process(vector<complex<float>>::iterator begin, vector<complex<float>>::iterator end);
```

This however only works for vectors, not C-style arrays, std::arrays, ranges, etc.

After some fiddling, lots of Google and a little bit of luck, I managed to construct this:

```
// Example 2
using namespace std; // not in original code
template<
    template<typename T> class C,
    typename T,
    typename C<T>::iterator iterator
    >
Errc const& process(typename C<T>::iterator begin, typename C<T>::iterator end);
```

I am not even sure if that works but it compiles at least. What I think it does, is define a function that processes any container with an arbitrary value type. This would be a problem, as I can only process std::complex (or maybe similar complex floating point values) but not std::string for example.

What I would like to do:

```
// Example 3
using namespace std; // not in original code
template<
    template<typename complex<float>> class C,
    typename C<complex<float>>::iterator iterator
    >
Errc const& process(typename C<complex<float>>::iterator begin, typename C<complex<float>>::iterator end);
```

But this apparently is not the way to do this. I am about 60% percent sure I also messed something up in example 2.

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with `template<typename Iter> void process(Iter begin, Iter end)`?

Comment: I wanted to only have function definitions for iterators pointing to `std::complex`. I guess just using `typename Iter` would also make the function valid for `string` or any other object, or am I wrong?

Comment: It would be valid if the function only accessed the values in a way which was also supported by that value type. In which case, the general opinion by programmers of  C++ (as with other languages supporting [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism)) is that you shouldn't try to prevent the user from doing that.

Comment: You mean that if I simply have an arbitrary iterator but use it with `Iter->real()`, my approach would limit a user to only input iterators to `std::complex<float>` while your approach lets the user provide iterators to any type that supports `real()`? That actually does make a lot of sense

Comment: Exactly. In practice, any "interesting" algorithm will access the values in enough different ways that it'll naturally break if you pass something that it can't deal with properly, though that's not a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: The primary disadvantage is that when you do pass something weird (like iterators to pointers to complexes), it'll give the user weird and potentially unhelpful error messages.

Comment: Yes that might be true. However the error messages of any complicated templating error are hard to read anyways. The advantage is that I can also pass IPP and CUDA complex values, which is quite handy for my purposes. Thank you for digging into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example 2 is nearly correct

```
template<
    template<typename T> class C,
    typename T,
    typename C<T>::iterator iterator // That is wrong
    >
Errc const& process(typename C<T>::iterator begin, typename C<T>::iterator end);
```

it should be:

```
template<template <typename> class C, typename T>
Errc const& process(typename C<T>::iterator begin, typename C<T>::iterator end);
```

But issue is that `C`/`T` are not deducible, and you have to call it like:

```
process<std::vector, std::complex<float>>(v.begin(), v.end());
```

And `C-array` and `std::array` doesn't match `template <typename> class C` neither (and `std::vector` has default allocator too :-/)

Simpler would just be

```
template<typename Iterator>
Errc const& process(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
```

possibly with some SFINAE

```
template <typename Iterator,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::complex<float>,
                                          std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>, int> = 0>
Errc const& process(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
```

or C++20 requires:

```
template <typename Iterator>
Errc const& process(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
requires (std::is_same_v<std::complex<float>, std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type);
```

If you want only **contiguous** sequences, you might use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)

```
Errc const& process(std::span<std::complex<float>)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Your solution worked although I could not use the aliases `std::is_same_v` and `std::enable_if_t` because of C++11. But it's working now and I am thankful

Answer (score 2):

You could use `std::iterator_traits` and compare the `value_type` of the iterator with the type you'd like to support:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template<class It, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same_v<class std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type,
                   std::complex<float>
    >, int> = 0>
Errc const& process(It begin, It end) {
   //...
}
```

Alternative:

```
template<class It>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<class std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type,
                                std::complex<float>>, Errc const&>
process(It begin, It end) {
    //...
}
```

If SFINAE is not needed, `static_assert`:

```
template<class It>
Errc const& process(It begin, It end) {
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<class std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type,
                       std::complex<float>>);
    //...
}
```

Comment: My understanding of the question is that OP wants to make the function more generalized, not restrict it. It's a bit unclear though.

Comment: @super As I understand it, the wanted generalization only concerns the container type, not the value type (which should be `std::complex<float>`). I think my answer shows how that can be done in two ways: If there are `process` overloads, one of the SFINAE versions can be used. If no `process` overloads exist, the `static_assert` version can be used to give nicer compilation errors.

Comment: Yes, reading it again I think you are right.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, that was exactly what I wanted and your solution worked perfect for me. I marked your answer as helpful but the other answer was a little more verbose. Thank you very much for the fast help