# Pass Iterator to template but only accept certain data types

Tags: c++

I am struggling a bit with passing iterators to functions.

I want to accomplish something like this.
void func(MyClass* foo, numberOfFoo);

But I want to use iterators and it should support any stl-container.

I know I can write a function like this:

```
void foo(std::vector<MyClass>::const_iterator start, std::vector<MyClass>::const_iterator end){
    while (start != end){
        //Do stuff with *start, which has type MyClass
        ++start;
    }
}
```

I also know that I can write a Template like this:

```
template <class Iterator>
void foo( Iterator first, Iterator last){
    while (start != end){
        //Do stuff with *start, which has ANY type
        ++start;
    }
}
```

But I now want to write a Template, where the data type of the iterators are of type MyClass and no other.

In the end the following should happen:

```
std::vector<MyClass> vectorOfClass;
std::array<MyClass> arrayOfClass;
std::vector<int> vectorOfInt;

foo(vectorOfClass.begin(), vectorOfClass.end()); //Should compile
foo(arrayOfClass.begin(), arrayOfClass.end());   //Should compile
foo(vectorOfInt.begin(), vectorOfInt.end());     //Should not compile
```

Maybe the solution is very easy, but I don't know what to search for.

Thanks for your help already.

Comment: so you want to write a template specialized on the basis of a particular class?? I am sorry, I don't get what your goal is.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430461/container-iterator-template-for-one-value-type/67430721) something like what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need overloads, you don't need SFINAE, and could go for a simple `static_assert` using [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). A `static_assert` makes it possible to generate a really clear compilation error.

```
#include <iterator>     // std::iterator_traits
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_same_v

template<class It>
void foo(It first, It last) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<class std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type, MyClass>,
                  "Only ranges of MyClass objects are accepted by foo()");
    //...
}
```